# How to add a folder reference in my the Pod project in post install?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

So, I am trying to add a folder reference in a target that was created by cocoapods.

I found this solution, but it is not working for me. https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3521

I am on cocoapods 0.39. And I only changed the `projects` to `pods_project` since that was deprecated.

Also how do you enable logging when running `pod update`. I tried `pod update --verbose`, but my `puts` is not being displayed. :/

**=========== UPDATED ===========**

```
post_install do |installer|
    puts "printing tests"
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if target.name == "TargetWhereToAddTheFolderOrFileReference"
          source_files = target.source_build_phase.files
          folderReference = installer.project.add_file_reference("/AbsolutePath/To/FileOrFolder", installer.project.pod_group("PodGroupWhereToAddTheFileOrFolder"), true)
          target.source_build_phase.add_file_reference(btsdata, true)
        end
      end
    end
end

post_install do |installer|
    // another post install script is here.
end
```

I've attached the script that is failing plus there was another post_install script below it. That `puts "printing tests"` is not being called as well....

**=========== UPDATED ENDS ===========**

Comment: Can I see your post install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I think the script will only execute the last post_install and not 
both. Can you put the code inside the first post_install into the last one?

Comment: Guess what, that works....now it have other issues, but that is something else. thanks